# Fat free framework : configure mapper for records grouping

Tags: php, pagination, fat-free-framework

I need to use pagination but records source involves many tables so, as usual, I create a view for better handling this situation.
My problem is that tables relations are one-to-many type (that is right, I need to filter children tables for some specific values) so I guess I must group by using navigation display fields.

This behaviour is not yet managed by standard pagination nor by any plugin (as far as I know).

Some google searches gives me some ideas : I must grouping at mapper configuration level before use mapper with pagination.

Unfortunately I cannot find any decent docs that covers this behaviour, anyone can help me?

Comment: Hi,.. yes paginated grouping is sometimes tricky. You can check Cortex (a plugin I wrote). https://github.com/ikkez/f3-cortex/ it should work with these situations.

Comment: Thank you ikkez, I'll check your plugin! Could Cortex coexist with standard mapper? Which impact could have using Cortex on a previous developed webapp?